# var = twint.storage.panda.Tweets_df. What is this?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, class, object

I'm new with Python and I'm using Twint. In order to create a DataFrame from the scraped twits, I must run the following code:

```
c = twint.Config()
c.Hide_output = output

twint.run.Search(c)

Tweets_df = twint.storage.panda.Tweets_df
```

The thing is that I don't understand what type of action is performing the `twint.storage.panda.Tweets_df` line. It seems that it creates a DataFrame object. In fact, `Tweets_df` is a `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` instance, but that's not the way (as far as I know) to create objects from a class. I mean: I was expecting to see that expression with parentheses; something like `var = pd.DataFrame()`. So... what's going on?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `twint.storage.panda` Tweets_df is initially set to a None value it is likely that it is set to the value of a the object you're talking about at a later point in the code.  So the code would look something like this.

```py
#Our code module
data1 = None

class ourClass:
    def __init__(self):
       self.some_data = 0

data1 = ourClass()
```

then when we

```
import ourCode

variable = ourCode.data1
variable2 = ourCode.data1
```

we end up with variable and variable2 referencing the same object.

Link to twint source code 
https://github.com/twintproject/twint/blob/master/twint/storage/panda.py

Comment: Interesting! Thank you very much for your help